# Console-like message box in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

[Messagebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIw5H.png)
[image]

How can i create something like this in WPF? A box where i can display text messages, older ones move towards the top rather than disappear. Something like a chat.
It doesn't need to be fancy with scroll bar, i just need a message box that has the capacity to display multiple text messages. Time when the message was created would be handy but is not necessary.

Comment: I usually just use an `ObservableCollection` of `Message` objects that i bind a `ItemsControl` to.  `Message` has a `Time` and `Text` property.  The template is just 2 `TextBlock` bound to properties of `Message`. Add items to the collection as needed, the binding handles the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use windows as a dialog and bind your message to listview from that dialog. I made sample application to demonstrade you how you could do it. This is only a sample to show you very basic messaging application. DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION.

MainWindow Example:

```
<Window x:Class="Messaging.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Messaging"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox Name="txtMessage" Width="200" Height="50" Margin="10" />
            <Button Name="btnSubmit" Content="submit" Width="200" Height="50" Click="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace Messaging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageStorage.Messages = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Message>();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.MessageContent = txtMessage.Text;
            message.PublishDate = DateTime.Now;

            MessageStorage.Messages.Add(message);

            MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(MessageStorage.Messages);
            messageDialog.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Message dialog wiew:

```
<Window x:Class="Messaging.MessageDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Messaging"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MessageDialog" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="lvMessages">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageContent}" Margin="0,10,10,0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate}" Margin="0,10,10,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Message Dialog code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace Messaging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MessageDialog.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MessageDialog : Window
    {
        public MessageDialog(ObservableCollection<Message> messages)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lvMessages.ItemsSource = messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.PublishDate);
        }
    }
}
```

MessageStorage class:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Messaging
{
    public static class MessageStorage
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and finallly the message class:

```
using System;

namespace Messaging
{
    public class Message
    {
        public string MessageContent { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.